# Resolved: Query that returns the output where one column matches all the values in another column

Tags: sql, oracle

Using oracle developer, I've run a query that results in the following table.  But I only want the results where column1 matches all the values columns 2 (3,4,8).  So the output would be 2, 3, but not 4. I'm sure there is a way to bring this result about without hard coding it?  I'm thinking its some sort of self-join?

```
    select column1, column2
    from table1
    where column1 in (
        select column1
        from table2
        where depth >= 100)
    order by column2;
```

Output:

```
    column1   column2
    3          2
    8          2
    4          2
    3          3
    4          3
    8          3
    4          4
```

Table2

```
    Column1     Area_Name       Depth
    1           Lake            40
    2           River           50
    3           Ocean           150
    4           Cliff           150
    5           Mountain        90
    6           Construction    60
    7           Building        50
    8           Random          100
    9           Also Random     50
    10          Another one     80
```

Needed output:

```
    column2
    2
    3
```

Ok, this is what I was looking for:

```
    SELECT table1.column1
    FROM table1
        INNER JOIN table2 
        ON table1.column2 = table2.column2
        WHERE table2.depth >= 100
    GROUP BY boat_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= (
        select count(*) 
        from table2
        where depth >= 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

```
WITH qry AS (
  SELECT column1, column2
    FROM table1
   WHERE column1 IN (
        SELECT column1
          FROM table2
         WHERE depth >= 100)
) 
SELECT t1.column2
  FROM qry t1 LEFT JOIN qry t2
    ON t1.column1 = t2.column1 AND t1.column2 = t2.column2
 GROUP BY t1.column2
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column1) FROM qry)
ORDER BY t1.column2
```

Output:

```
| COLUMN2 |
-----------
|       2 |
|       3 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef37b/4)**

Comment: I also need it to check another table so the my results are isolated to the point where it brings back values 3, 4, 8 in column 1.  Where would I place the query in the where clause in my original query?

Comment: @user2163396 It's hard to say guessing what's in that second table. Post sample data for both tables.

Comment: I adjusted my code to include yours, but I am still get the results 2, 3, AND 4.  I'm not too worried about duplicates, I can take care of that.  I just need to know how to ensure that 4 does not show up in the results as it does not fit my criteria.  So I need to figure out how I can set the criteria without hard coding it?

Comment: @user2163396 It's still hard to understand your question completely, but take a look at the updated answer. It might be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it doesn't do what I want it to do which is to check which values in column2 match all the values in column1 and return the results. The left Join does not do this? The output needs to be column2: 2, 3. I'm not certain how to ask the question in  different way.

Comment: Okay, another scenario:  Let's say I've done a query that brings about all the people who like either oranges, apples and bananas.  My query brings back 3 people who like either oranges, apples or bananas.  So what I want to now know is which of these people like all 3 fruits: oranges, apples, and bananas. According to my table, there are 2 people who like oranges, apples and bananas.  The query should get rid of people who only like 1 or 2 of the fruits.  I want people who like ALL 3.

Comment: @user2163396 Did you see sqlfiddle I've posted? It gives you exactly what you expected (column2: 2, 3), does it not? If it doesn't on your real data then you should consider to post relevant sample data from table1 (not the results from your query) and try to explain more clearly what you want.

Comment: Yes, I get the following error when I do: No more data to read from socket